# Style for button

Tags: css, button

How can I change a default style for button if I use webkit-appearance:button. I like to do something like this.

```
div {

      webkit-appearance:button
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(145,200,242,1) 0, rgba(137,163,200,1) 100%);

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? What is the intended result?

Comment: Can you add more information? What is the ID or class you're trying to select?

Comment: Also, use the following to apply for *most* major browsers; `webkit-appearance`,`appearance`,`-moz-appearance`

Comment: you can style a button by targeting it like any other element. button.class#id[name="name"]

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work. `-webkit-appearance` is used to change the default appearance of something, it's usually set to none. If you want it to look and behave like a default button, use a `<button>` element. Otherwise, remove the webkit appearance and just style it however you wish.

Comment: This is wrong. appearance can be used to look like a button. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Comment: Yes but why would you do so? That makes no sense, I've only ever seen and used it when setting to `none`. If you want it to look like a button, make it a button. Otherwise style it however you wish... And as for downvoting it, I was right. It doesn't work. You can't set appeance to button AND give it a gradient...

Comment: Yes, you are right about the gradient. But you said it doesn't work and as the OP is new, he may think it cannot be done at all.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes people get the wrong impression from what we say. Good answer though.:)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. First, there is no - in front of webkit:

```
-webkit-appearance:button
```

Second you have no ending semicolon on `-webkit-apperance:button;` and no browser prefix wich is needed for a chrome gradient:

```
div {

      webkit-appearance:button
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(145,200,242,1) 0, rgba(137,163,200,1) 100%);

}
```

Fix your coding to this:

```
div {

      -webkit-appearance:button;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(145,200,242,1) 0, rgba(137,163,200,1) 100%);

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/EQPTS/6/)
Also, as other have said, if you use apperance:button; and try to edit it with CSS, the appearance no longer works. If you want the look of a button, use the `<button>` element.

Comment: If you remove the `-webkit-appearance`, you'll see the gradient has no effect on the appearance whatsoever.

Comment: I don't have any result in Chrome if I run your code. I don't see linear-gradient... (((

Comment: Nothing. Only if I comment -webkit-appearance:button, I see a liner gradient. I think we can't apply linear-gradient for -webkit-appearance:button.

Comment: @Makeda see the bottom part of my answer. If you try and style a div with a appearance, the appearance is rendered obsolete. use the <button> element instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are trying to select the button is wrong. If you want to style a regular `<button>` element with a linear gradient your CSS selector needs to be as follows:

**HTML**

```
<button>Hello World</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(145,200,242,1) 0, rgba(137,163,200,1) 100%);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/85hpd/